# Issue with IEDriverServer and cropping screenshots

Tags: internet-explorer, screenshot, watir-webdriver

I am using Watir-WebDriver to run automated tests of our Rails application and spent the last couple of days exploring the possabilities of comparing screenshots of specific elements.

I am using this gem: `watir-extensions-element-screenshot` ([here](https://github.com/ansoni/watir-extensions-element-screenshot)) to capture a screenshot of a specific element. This gem captures a screenshot of the full page and then crops it to single out the requested element.

This all works pretty well in Chrome and Firefox, but Internet Explorer is causing issues. When I run my automated test, the `crop!` function throws the following exception:
`ChunkyPNG::OutOfBounds: Original image width is too small!`

This exception is thrown when `crop_width + x > width` where `crop_width` is the width of the element to be cropped, `x` is the x-coordinate of the top left corner of the image to be cropped and `width` is the width of the original image.

When I print some of the values during testing I can indeed confirm the values above:
`crop_width: 940, crop_height: 562`
`x: 363, y: 211`
`width: 900, height: 520   #why are these so small?`

When I manually capture a screenshot of the same element in IRB, it works just fine:
`irb(main):013:0> b = Watir::Browser.new :ie`
`=> #<Watir::Browser:0x422422cc url="http://localhost:5555/" title="WebDriver">`
`irb(main):014:0> b.goto 'localhost:3000'`
`irb(main):015:0> b.div(:id => 'lbcontent').screenshot('ie_test.png')`
`crop_width: 940, crop_height: 562`
`x: 371, y: 195`
`width: 1680, height: 909`
`=> #<File:ie_test.png (closed)>`

So apparantly the IEDriverServer does some resizing while capturing a screenshot but it all works fine in IRB.. anyone has an explanation and/or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

The element screenshot extension is first taking a screenshot of the browser window using Watir's built-in methods:

```
browser.screenshot.save(file)
```

The problem here is that you can get different image sizes depending on the browser you are using:

- In Firefox, the screenshot will include everything on the page. This includes the parts of the page that a user would have to scroll down or right to see.
- In contrast, Chrome and IE screenshot exactly what the user currently sees. Anything that you have to scroll to see will not be included in the image. This means that the image size will be dependent on the browser window dimensions.

Ultimately, this means that Chrome and IE will throw this exception whenever you need to scroll to the image. For example, if the image width is 500 but the browser width is only 250, the exception will occur.

**Workaround**

Given that you had no problems when the browser window was larger, I would suggest maximizing the browser before taking the cropped screenshot.

Try:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :ie
b.goto 'localhost:3000'
b.window.maximize                                       # Added line
b.div(:id => 'lbcontent').screenshot('ie_test.png')
```

Note that you will still have problems if the image is still outside this area.

Comment: I actually maximize the browser window in my automated tests. When I run the test in IE, I notice the browser window flickers when the screenshot is made. I'm guessing this flicker is actually the IEDriverServer resizing the browser window to 900x520 to create the screenshot and then resizing it back to it's original size. However, if this is the case, then why can't I reproduce this in IRB?

Comment: It seems quite unexpected that the IEDriverServer would know the difference between your script running vs IRB. When using IRB, I too can see the browser flicker during the screenshot. However the saved image is the right size. Out of curiosity, what happens if you output the browser size right before taking the screenshot? Does it also say "900"?

Comment: Ok things are starting to get weird now..  
When I added a simple `puts browser.window.size` the screenshot actually works, no flicker or exceptions thrown.
Note that I added this in the Watir::Element.screenshot method, which is added in the `watir-extensions-element-screenshot` gem. Printing the `browser.window.size` anywhere else made no difference. And to answer your question Justin, printing the size says `width = 1680, height = 1050`

Comment: It must be some bug in the IEDriverServer. It would be good if you can create a reproducible example using just Selenium-Webdriver and logging a bug to that group.

Comment: I've started a clean project and created a minimal working example but have been unable to reproduce this issue after spending way too much time on this. Also, I've switched from ChunkyPNG to ImageMagick for image cropping (the latter is already used in my site-under-test) thus I don't really feel like spending more time trying to figure out why this (very narrow) use-case fails. I'll accept this answer since it helped me solve/workaround my problem.